Api Management stv2, unable to remove region powershell
After uptdating apim from stv1 to stv2 i'm not able remove region via powershell with this command:
Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $APIMresourceGroupName -Name $APIMaccountName | Remove-AzApiManagementRegion -Location "North Europe" | Set-AzApiManagement

it worked until there was v1. Now I got following error:
Set-AzApiManagement: 'SubnetResourceId' does not match expected pattern '^/subscriptions/[^/]/resourceGroups/[^/]/providers/Microsoft.(ClassicNetwork|Network)/virtualNetworks/[^/]/subnets/[^/]$'.
If i just run
Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $APIMresourceGroupName -Name $APIMaccountName | Remove-AzApiManagementRegion -Location "North Europe"

the region is removed from the object, but if i se the modify with set-azapimanagent i got error written before.
I'm using latest cmdlet api.management. There is someone that have same problem?
Thanks

Can you explain what exactly are you trying to do with Set-AzApiManagement. Because the error 'SubnetResourceId' does not match expected pattern says that the resource ID format is not correctly passed. @Emanuele

And it is not possible directly to remove a region after migrating to stv2. Instead you need to export the api management template and import it into another region. Is that works for you.@Emanuele

Hi, with that command i trying to remove the region. Is a command that i use from i couple of years and is it written in microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/remove-azapimanagementregion?view=azps-12.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-11.3.0
from portal i'm able to do that. North europe is a secondary region, the primary is west europe

Yes, removing region is working but the issue is with set-AzApiManagement. @Emanuele

@Jahnavi do you have any prevision if microsoft fix it?

I did not get it. Can you elaborate. @Emanuele

@Emanuele Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $APIMresourceGroupName -Name $APIMaccountName | Remove-AzApiManagementRegion -Location "North Europe" | Set-AzApiManagement command worked as expected for stv2.1 platform version in my case. You need to review your command as you are getting SubnetResourceId related error which I believe we are not using in the command.

hi, i tried to review the command but i do not understand what is the problem. I see that now there is a  public ip address respect v1

Can you provide the subnetresourceID which exactly showing in the apim get ouput. @Emanuele

Get-AzApiManagement retrieves the resource from ARM. Remove-AzApiManagementRegion just removes region from resource in powershell memory. Set-AzApiManagement actually saves the data back to ARM and initiates the update. This is where validation error is coming from. You can use JSON resource view in Azure Portal to double-check what is the value for SubnetResourceId for the regions you're not removing.

I found the resolution here https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/22565 :
### CHANGE SKU
$apimSKU = Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $APIMresourceGroupName -Name $APIMaccountName
$apimSKU.VirtualNetwork.SubnetResourceId = $apimSKU.VirtualNetwork.SubnetResourceId -replace "microsoft.network", "Microsoft.Network" -replace "resourcegroups", "resourceGroups" -replace "virtualnetworks", "virtualNetworks"
$apimSKU.Sku = "Developer"

Set-AzApiManagement -InputObject $apimSKU

above a small example. Basically with migration to v2 the $apimSKU.VirtualNetwork.SubnetResourceId is in lowercase and Set-AzApiManagement does not manage it.
Regards

If you are trying to remove the secondary location from APIM resource stv2.1 platform version then below command should work for you as it worked for me.
Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $APIMresourceGroupName -Name $APIMaccountName | Remove-AzApiManagementRegion -Location "East US" | Set-AzApiManagement


Post executing this command, my apim instance got updated as shown below.

Please review your command as the error you are getting is related to subnet.
For Premium tier-
I have enabled internal vnet in APIM instance and executed same command successfully which removed the secondary location.


I had these two locations-

Once the APIM instance gets updated successfully you won't be able to see Service is being updated message and then secondary location will get removed.

Please make sure to execute the command when the service is not in update state.

i have premium tier, not developer. And apim is vnet injected.  Maybe something changed from v1 to v2.

@Emanuele I believe it will also work for premium tier, is it feasible for you to test on a new v2 instance?

@Emanuele same command worked for premium tier too with vnet enabled. I would suggest to create a new instance and try as the command does work

Is a bit hard to us to try with a new instance. I will open a ticket in microsoft and let you know

@Emanuele I believe it has something to do with the way it migrated. Do you have any other instance of stv2 if yes you can try the same command and see if it works

we have production but is still in v1. We will migrate in the next week

@Emanuele Lets hope the command works.

Hello i fixed it following this topic https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/22565

@Emanuele You can add your solution here as an answer
